# react-redux-spinner won't render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was searching for a loading spinner for react+redux and came across the [react-redux-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-spinner) library. I included it in my project, added the reducer, called `[pendingTask]: begin/end` in my actions, added the Spinner component to render, but it just won't show at all, even though in the redux logs I can see that pending tasks in the store are incremented and decremented accordingly to the action called. Here is some of my code:

**store**:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  pendingTasks: pendingTasksReducer
  // other reducers
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer, /* middlewares */);
export default store;
```

**actions**

```
export const fetchData = params => {
  const request = params => ({
    type: 'FETCH_REQUEST',
    [pendingTask]: begin,
    payload: { params }
  });
  const success = data => ({
    type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS',
    [pendingTask]: end,
    payload: { data }
  });
  const failure = error => ({
    type: 'FETCH_FAILURE',
    [pendingTask]: end,
    payload: { error }
  });

  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(request(params));
    try {
      const res = await service.fetchData(params);
      dispatch(success(res.data));
      return res.data;
    } catch (e) {
      const msg = e.toString();
      dispatch(failure(msg));
      return Promise.reject(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

**page**

```
const Page = props => {
  const { data } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(params) {
      try {
        await props.fetchData(params);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData(data.params);
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
    { 
      data.map(({ field1, field2 }, key) => ({
        <div>{field1}: {field2}</div>
      }));
    }
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { data } = state;
  return { data };
};

const actionCreators = {
  fetchData: actions.fetchData
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Page);
```

**app component**

```
export const App = props => {
  return (
    <main className="App">
      <Spinner config={{ trickeRate: 0.02 }} />
      <Page/>
    </main>
  );
}
```

I've double-checked that I use the correct names for the store and for the actions, and they do fire up - but the spinner itself never gets rendered on the page at all, even though with each action the `pendingTasks` value change. What could I possibly do wrong or miss here? Infinitely grateful in advance for pointing out!

Comment: There's a typo in `config`: `trickeRate` ~> `trickleRate`, but if that doesn't fix it your best best would be to create a small StackBlitz/CodeSandbox example that shows the problem.

Comment: Everything works now!